# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1- Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

i'm using retrofit for my app. when i try to access webservice,`onFailure` i'm getting `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1`.

this is postman response

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "order status updated"
}
```

Oncreate

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://example.com/sample/")
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
token="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9";
id_order= 288;
status="process";
update();
```

method

```
public void update(){
        WebserviceAPI apiService =retrofit.create(WebserviceAPI.class);
        Call<UpdateOrderResponse> call = apiService.updateOrder("pickorder",token,id_order,status);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UpdateOrderResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UpdateOrderResponse> call, Response<UpdateOrderResponse> response) {

                UpdateOrderResponse result = response.body();
                Log.d("orderstatus", "body: "+result);
                returnstatus=result.isStatus();
                msg= result.getMessage();

                if(returnstatus){
                    Log.d("orderstatus","status ok");
                }else{
                    Log.d("orderstatus","status not ok");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UpdateOrderResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("proceedFail",""+t.getMessage());

            }
        });

    }
```

Response class

```
public class UpdateOrderResponse {

    boolean status;
    String message;

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding this inside onResponse() `UpdateOrderResponse updateOrderResponse=new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(response.toString(),UpdateOrderResponse.class);` // this will convert the reponse to object type.
`

Comment: but the thing is `onResponse()` not calling

Comment: add code for `WebserviceAPI.class` here